# kubectl update service with new label and service names

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is it possible to update an external loadbalancer service in kubernetes with a new spec from an yaml file.

I can do rolling updates of the deployments but how can I update services, primarily not changing the external IP address.

Thanks, Rajesh

Answer (score 6):

If you do not want to edit on the living or already deployed  manifest file. you can edit the service manifest file on your computer and use **apply** action instead of create.
For instance,

```
kubectl apply -f service-manifest.yaml
```

**It will work without changing already existing external IPs**

Answer (score 2):

I think I have the answer

env KUBE_EDITOR="nano" kubectl edit svc/my-service

And I can edit the service with the new selector/labels.

I am not sure if there is a better option

Comment: Good one. Thank you. It helps me with a similar case.